# JSP Page error While inserting data

Tags: java, jsp, java-server

[image]

im noob to Programming Please look into the following code.while running the code it gave me some nullpointer exception

Comment: Please Zoom in to see it clear ..

Comment: Do not post the code as screenshot please post the code inline in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never call `establishConnection` in your `Dao` class.
As result of this `con` is null.

add the method `establishConnection` in the `constructor` of `personDao`:

```
public personDao(){
    establishConnection();
}
```

and try it again.

Furthermore read the `Java code conventions`.
A class name should start with uppercase: `PersonDao` would by correct and it follows the `Camelcase` code conventions.

Comment: Thank you Beike .. Can you please help me out with <Jsp: setProperty> as u can see i comment out jsp property tags, beacuse it was giving an error of "Cannot find any information on property 'Name' in a bean of type 'Gravity.PersonInfoBean'"

Comment: Hey solve the issue .. calling it property name with uppercase letter.